# How do I display confidence intervals for fitted values of RDD in R?

Tags: r

I would like to display the confidence intervals for the two fitted regression lines on each side of the cutoff in a Regression Discontinuity Design in R (preferably as shaded areas).

Currently, I am using `rdplot` from the `rdrobust` package, but I am open to any tips for adding the confidence intervals using other tools, e. g. `ggplot2`.

This is what my plot currently looks like:

[image: RD plot]

Thank you very much in advance!